# raise SlackLoginError(reply=reply) slackclient.server.SlackLoginError

Tags: python, slack, rtm

Running the below small script passing  OAuth Access Token as a token here :

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
import os

token = "*********"
sc = SlackClient(token)
print (sc.api_call("api.test"))
if sc.rtm_connect():
        print("Starter Bot connected and running!")
```

GETTING BELOW ERROR

```
Failed RTM connect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\320055379\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\slackclient\client.py", line 140, in rtm_connect
    self.server.rtm_connect(use_rtm_start=with_team_state, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\320055379\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\slackclient\server.py", line 168, in rtm_connect
    raise SlackLoginError(reply=reply)
slackclient.server.SlackLoginError
```

Answer (score 1):

the new granual scope does not support rtm anymore, you can try this link to create a classic bot https://api.slack.com/rtm#create_a_classic_slack_app